# How to use w3c validator api from program ( ex node.js )

Tags: node.js

I want to use [w3c validator api](http://validator.w3.org/docs/users.html) to check some htmls by using node.js.
I think that it is so inconvenience to validate each html to use [w3c validator page](http://validator.w3.org/).

So I try to check some htmls automatically to use w3c validator api by using node.js.
I make following code to request official api. But response is w3c validator page.
don't response api( format json ).

how to use w3c validator api by using node.js??

- request.js

  ```
  var url = require("url");
  var http = require("http");
  var events = require("events");
  var querystring = require('querystring');

  exports.post = function( request_url , parameters , handler , headerOptions ){
      return request( 'POST' , request_url , parameters , handler , headerOptions );
  }
  exports.get = function( request_url , handler , headerOptions ){
      return request( 'GET' , request_url , {} , handler , headerOptions );
  }


  var request = function( method , request_url , parameters , handler , headerOptions ){
      var parsedURL = url.parse( request_url,false );
      if( !parameters ){
          parameters = {};
      }
      var postData = querystring.stringify(parameters);
      var reqOptions = {
      "host": parsedURL['host'],
      "port": parsedURL['port']?parsedURL['port']:'80',
      "path": parsedURL['path'],
      "method": method,
      "headers": {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
      }
      };
      if( typeof headerOptions == 'object' ){
          for( var i in headerOptions ){
              reqOptions[i] = headerOptions[i];
          }
      }
      var req = http.request(reqOptions, function(res){
          res.setEncoding('utf-8');
          res.on('data', function (data) {
              handler(data);
          });
      });
      req.write(postData);
      req.end();
      return req;
  };
  ```
- w3cValidate.js

  ```
  var request = require('./request.js');
  request.get(
      //request url
      'http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.co.jp&output=json',
      //success handler
      function(res){
          console.log(res);
      }
  ).on('error',function(e){
      //error handler
      console.log(e);
  });
  ```
- command line

  ```
  node w3cValidate.js
  ```
- expected response

  ```
  like this : http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.co.jp&output=json.
  ```
- actual response

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">


  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>The W3C Markup Validation Service</title>
  <link rev="made" href="mailto:www-validator@w3.org" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <link rev="start" href="./" title="Home Page" />
  <style type="text/css" media="all">
  @import "
  ./style/base";
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/combined"></script>

  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, HyperText Markup Language, Validation,  W3C Markup Validation Service" />
  <meta name="description" content="W3C's easy-to-use markup validation service, based on SGML and XML parsers." />
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/validator-whatsnew.atom" />
  </head>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the add the query string do the end of your path

```
"path": parsedURL['path'] + parsedURL.search,
```

And btw, the `res` object in the request is a stream. It'll keep emitting `data` events until the entire page is downloaded. Your current code might call your handler several times. If you want to call it only once, buffer the `data` events and call the callback when the `end` event is emitted.

You're probably better off using a fully developed and tested module like [mikeal's request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). You're doing something similar already in your `request.js` file.